# Can't get ball to bounce on an animated mesh

Tags: animation, physics

I seem to be having a consistent problem with physics in Blender, regardless of version. I sometimes have to delete and add the exact same Rigid Body settings before I can get it to behave how I expected.

In this case, I have a mesh which is animated by music. The ball is dropping onto the mesh and should then interact with the animated peaks and troughs. I tried every conceivable setting but could not get the animated mesh to knock the ball around. Then I went into material preview mode, and came out again, and then the mesh interacted properly.

Ok. So I then scaled the sphere until it was ten times as large. It instantly stopped interacting with the mesh when I replayed the physics.

The waveform mesh is set to music via the 'Bake sound to F Curves' setting in the Graph Editor, applied to the first key frame. Is this what is causing the problem? Do I have to unbake the sound and then bake it again everytime I change a setting in the Rigid Body Physics? If so, how?

Or have I chosen the wrong type of collision settings for my passive waveform object and my active ball object?

[image]

[image]